# Bind Data in Ajax Uploader grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, file-io, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm not able to replicate this problem, My problem is how to bind data in CuteWebUI Ajax Uploader grid, I am using CuteWebUI Ajax Uploader for upload attachment, What i'm doing i'm upload document, store it to a folder then save their path to database, Now i dnt know how to bind that data which save in database in CuteWebUI Ajax Uploader grid on page refresh.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NocUpload.aspx.cs" Inherits="IMCU.Pages.NocUpload" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CuteWebUI.AjaxUploader" Namespace="CuteWebUI" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="AddAssetUpdatePanel" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <cc1:UploadAttachments ID="Attachments1" runat="server" OnUploadCompleted="Attachments1_UploadCompleted"
                        ProgressPanelWidth="450" ShowCheckBoxes="false" RemoveButtonBehavior="Delete" ShowRemoveButtons="true" InsertText="Browse Document"
                        ProgressInfoStyle="padding-left:3px;font:normal 11px Tahoma;" OnAttachmentRemoveClicked="Attachments1_AttachmentRemoveClicked" OnPreRender="Attachments1_PreRender">
                        <CancelButtonStyle CssClass="Hidden" />
                    </cc1:UploadAttachments>
                    <br />                    
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace IMCU.Pages
{
    public partial class NocUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Attachments1_UploadCompleted(object sender, CuteWebUI.UploaderEventArgs[] args)
        {
            string TempUploadFolder = Server.MapPath("~/TempUpload/" + Session["UserId"] + "/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(TempUploadFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(TempUploadFolder);

            foreach (CuteWebUI.UploaderEventArgs arg in args)
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = arg.OpenStream())
                {
                    arg.CopyTo(TempUploadFolder + arg.FileName.Replace(" ", "_"));
                   // arg.GetTempFilePath();
                }
            }
        }

        public string rename(string name)
        {
            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(name).Replace("%", "_").Replace(" ", "_");
        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Attachments1_AttachmentRemoveClicked(object sender, CuteWebUI.AttachmentItemEventArgs args)
        {

            //if the upload file has saved into the photos folder  
            if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/TempUpload/" + Session["UserId"] + "/" + args.Item.FileName.Replace(" ", "_"))))
            {
                //delete it  
                File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/TempUpload/" + Session["UserId"] + "/" + args.Item.FileName.Replace(" ", "_")));
            }
        }



 protected void Attachments1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//            Attachments1.GetItemsTable();   
        }

 }
```